# Timing to move indoor vegetable seedlings to 4" pots

Tags: vegetables, germination, transplanting

I have started some vegetable seeds indoors (SF/Bay Area) in small 1"x1" pods.  The seeds have sprouted but not sure when is a good time to move them to 4" indoor pots before planting them in the outdoors vegetable box?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's recommended that you wait until after the first true leaves appear before transplanting seedlings.

I plant my seeds into small grow-bags made of plant-fiber.  The roots can then grow right through the bottom and when this happens i know it's time to transplant. I also seed mine outside so I don't need to harden off. And I can then plant without removing the grow bag minimizing root shock.

Comment: Where do you get these vegetable fiber bags and do they work with a heating mat since I believe I would need some heat to germinate. Also a picture of the vegetable fiber bag would be great.

Comment: 200 pcs plant-fiber  Nursery Pots Seedling-raising bags Garden Supplies Can degrade  Environmental protection   Size 8*10cm
http://s.aliexpress.com/iiyu2Yzq
And I've never used a heating pad so can't comment on that.  But aren't heating pads used in greenhouses etc rather then indoors.  And indoors might be hot enough for germination to occur.

Comment: Thanks. Reg not using heating pads, what temperature is needed indoors (without a heating mat) to germinate vegetable seeds?

Comment: Most will germinate at room temperature. See http://tomclothier.hort.net/page11.html for optimum ranges

Comment: You are full of information. Thank you for pointing everyone to these great resources.